# How can Iconvert hashmap back from byte[]?

Tags: java, hashmap, objectmapper

I have converted the hashmap to byte [] by using object mapper. Like below

```
private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<>();
            entries.put("triggerId","123");
            entries.put("webhookId","456");

byte[] message=objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(entries)
```

Now I want to convert it back to hashmap. How can I do this?

Comment: What does the data in the array look like?

Comment: It is getting converted into byte of array like [12,13,14,15]

Answer (score 1):

You have to readValue using jackson object mapper. Like below

```
 Map result = objectMapper.readValue(message, Map.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible